# Score of randomizedlasso() in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to know what does the 'score' parameter mean in randomizedlasso().

- make 200 random subsets with training data (default)
- run lasso() on each subsets
- delete features of 0 parameter vector from subsets
- make union list of features from subsets
- score of feature F is (number of subsets F remains / 200). If F is remaining only one subset, the score will be 0.005

Is it right understanding?